# Storing CSS in mysql database

Tags: html, mysql, css, stylesheet

I'm storing CSS (stylesheets) in a MySQL database, so when I call it, I only have one way, which is to echo it in the page itself. Is there anyway I can treat the database data as a .css file basically?

Comment: if you just store the css in a text column and output it with a server side language of your choice it should work fine.

Comment: Or you could store it as binary data similarly to what is done with images, although I do not think that confers any advantages over what martincarlin87 is suggesting.

Comment: It does, for eye-candy purposes, I'm trying to refrain from loading it directly in the page, other than that, it loads perfectly.

Comment: You mean you want to eliminate the echo and mysql query statements from your code? What do you mean "eye candy" purposes.

Comment: Not the mysql query, the echo, yes, when I echo it on the page, under viewing the source, the stylesheet shows in the page, I'm trying to eliminate that.

Comment: Have you thought about having a dedicated page to pull out and display the css, and using the css header `header("Content-type: text/css");` - then include that dynamic page where needed.

Comment: From your question I assume that the CSS is 'static', by which I mean it is the same for every page? In that case, it would be useful to give the CSS file a cache header, so it doesn't have to be downloaded every time someone visits a page. This will improve the speed of your website.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to read the CSS once during start-up and save it to a file somewhere within your deploy folder, and then reference it in code with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`. How exactly you do this will depend on your environment and specific web server.

In any case, it is always preferred to have the CSS as an external resource for a variety of reasons, e.g. because CSS resources are cached by the web browsers as opposed to dynamic pages.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to just go with loading from a .css file it's self, thanks for the help.

Comment: Why? What made you change your database solution?